# How create table variable with join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT  pr.Name                                                 AS ProfileName,
        pr.Code                                                 AS ProfileCode
FROM    dbo.CurrencyOperations co
JOIN dbo.CurrencyTransfers ct
    ON ct.OperId = co.id    
JOIN dbo.Accounts aco
    ON aco.id = ct.CreditId
    AND aco.Code LIKE '100%'
JOIN    dbo.cnbCashInRoad cr
    ON cr.CashInOperId = co.Id      
JOIN dbo.Labors lb
    ON lb.id = co.LaborId
JOIN dbo.Profiles pr
    ON pr.id = lb.ProfileId
```

How insert this query in TABLE variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using a temporary table.  That way, you can do:

```
select pr.name, pr.code
into #tablevar
from . . . ;
```

To use a table variable, you need to define it first and then insert:

```
declare @tablevar table (name varchar(255), code varchar(255));

insert into @tablevar (name, code)
    <your query here>;
```

Comment: In SQL Studio I have many syntax errors. Can write full query, please?

Comment: Rather confusing to name your temp table `#tablevar`.

Comment: @AndriiTkachenko . . . Both of these should be easy to write without errors.  The `into` clause goes after all the column have been listed in the `SELECT`.  In the second, the keyword `table` was misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this

First create a `temp table`, which will act as your `table variable`

```
declare @tempTable table (name varchar(your field length), code varchar(your field length))
```

now insert your date into this temp table

```
insert into @tempTable (name, code)
SELECT pr.Name, -- no alias here
       pr.Code  -- no alias here
FROM   dbo.CurrencyOperations co
  JOIN dbo.CurrencyTransfers ct ON ct.OperId = co.id    
  JOIN dbo.Accounts aco ON aco.id = ct.CreditId
                       AND aco.Code LIKE '100%'
  JOIN dbo.cnbCashInRoad cr ON cr.CashInOperId = co.Id      
  JOIN dbo.Labors lb ON lb.id = co.LaborId
  JOIN dbo.Profiles pr ON pr.id = lb.ProfileId
```

now just use it like a normal table, for example

```
select * 
from   @tempTable
```